# Javascript IF-ELSE Login Page Error, Can't seem to figure it out

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

Ok, i am a Web Developer or more of a hobby in Web Development and i am making a sign in page with HTML, CSS and JS. So i made two textboxes (Username, Password) with ids matching above and i use variables to set them to their value but what i need to do is to look at the value and if it equals blahblah and password equals blahblahblah then go to blahblahblah and yes i know i could use or should use a server side language but my server does not support server side, Here is my IF ELSE javascript code

```
var Username = document.getElementById("Username")
var Password = document.getElementById("Password")
if (Username.value = "Username", Password.value = "Password")
{
    window.location.href = "Place.html"
}
else
{
    var WRONG = document.getElementById("WRONG");
    WRONG.style = "color: red;"
}
```

Also, Happy July 4th!!

Comment: in your if use `==` instead on just one `=` and replace the `,` with `&&`

Comment: ... and instead of the comma operator, use and operator.

Comment: And for .... sake, **do not** verify password client side....

Comment: Yes i know about the verify password client side, inprotective and all but this is a external js script so i should be protected from inexperienced people and i will try the == and &&

Comment: That's not how this works. That's not how any of this works.

Comment: Whats now how this works @Lukas Bach

Comment: I think you should look at some basic JavaScript tutorials...

Comment: @Zero If the script runs on the browser, everyone has accessed to it as long as they can access the page. JavaScript usually runs on the browser. The only people that will not be able to access your script is people who don't know how to use their browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` where comparing two items. You also want to use `&&` or `||` where comparing multiple sets of items. In this case we will use `&&` because we want them both to equal a value.

**Note:** As mentioned in the comments validate the password server side.

```
var Username = document.getElementById("Username")
var Password = document.getElementById("Password")
if (Username.value == "Username" && Password.value == "Password") {
  window.location.href = "Place.html"
}
else {
  var WRONG = document.getElementById("WRONG");
  WRONG.style = "color: red;"
}
```

Comment: I will also try this

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator is meant for assigning values to a variable.

The `==` operator is meant for comparing values (or event better `===` which compares value and type).

Also use the `&&` operator for multiple booleans.

For your code I'd suggest replacing the `if` statement with something more like `if(Username.value === "Username" && Password.value === "Password")`

Comment: Can you please explain the ===, i can get == from other languages but i don't get ===?

Comment: it means that the types must also be the same `1 === "1" is false` where as `1 == "1" is true` or `1 == true is true` and `1 === true is false`

Comment: Well if you have a String `var str = "5";`
And you compare it to a number `var num = 5;`
This will evaluate to `true`: `str == num;`
However this will evaluate to `false`: `str === num;`